# Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\rndigita\system\database\mysql.php on line 21

Tags: php, mysql

i m facing this problem when i load my website. can any body help me out to solve this problem. every this is configured properly. database name user info is correct, same as on my local host. its working on live but showing this error on local host.

```
<?php

final class MySQL {

    private $link;



    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {

        if (!$this->link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)) {

            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link using ' . $username . '@' . $hostname);

        }


        if (!mysql_select_db($database, $this->link)) {

            trigger_error('Error: Could not connect to database ' . $database);

        }



        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->link);

        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->link);

        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $this->link);

        mysql_query("SET SQL_MODE = ''", $this->link);

    }



    public function query($sql) {

        $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->link);



        if ($resource) {

            if (is_resource($resource)) {

                $i = 0;



                $data = array();



                while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {

                    $data[$i] = $result;



                    $i++;

                }



                mysql_free_result($resource);



                $query = new stdClass();

                $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();

                $query->rows = $data;

                $query->num_rows = $i;



                unset($data);



                return $query;  

            } else {

                return true;

            }

        } else {

            trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);

            exit();

        }

    }



    public function escape($value) {

        return mysql_real_escape_string($value, $this->link);

    }



    public function countAffected() {

        return mysql_affected_rows($this->link);

    }



    public function getLastId() {

        return mysql_insert_id($this->link);

    }   



    public function __destruct() {

        mysql_close($this->link);

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: you mixed up mysql and mysqli

Comment: Use 


   `$con=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    mysqli_select_db($con,"test");`

as you use mysqli not mysql

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com He actually use much more `mysql_*` than `mysqli_*` so better to use `mysql_connect` no ? :p

Comment: @Bob0t yes why not and keep watching website hacked :) Go on!

Comment: As I recommended in my answer, using PDO is a much better idea :'P

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysqli_connect` (`mysqli_*`) and then using `mysql_*` function.

Try `mysql_connect` :)

Btw you should use PDO, `mysql_*` funcs are deprecated !